# Keep a specific property of a object/template non-reactive

Tags: meteor

On my site, users can recieve notifications on different events (such as a new comments on a user's post). Users can view these notifications on a special page in their profile. I want when a user come to that page that he can distinguish new ("unread") notifications. Namely, I want the following behavior:

1. When a user comes to a notifications page, any notification that has never before been shown on that page, is highlighted.
2. If a user leaves that page and comes later, only the new notifications (that has appeared in the meantime) are highlighted.
3. **Each notification is highlighted for as long as the user stays on the page**.
4. If a new notification appears while the user is on page, it is immediately loaded and shown and highlighted.
5. If a notification changes and/or is removed while the user stays on the page, the page reflects this change (preferably keeping the highlight status).

I start with having a `Notifications` collection that has a `read` field showing whether this notification is "read" (i.e. has already been shown). Now I can highlight only notifications that has `read` set to `false`. However, it will not get the required behavior in a simple way.

The main problem is point 3, because I must somehow mark that the notification has been read, but have this mark be taken into account only on the next visit to page.

For example, I might try to set notification's `read` field to `true` on template render (for example, in `Template.notification.rendered`), but it will immediately force notification template update and the highlighting will be removed.

So the particular problem is how to keep the initial value of `read` property and not redraw the template on this property change?

(I thought also of different approach such as relying on some user-side event such as user leaving the page, and updating `read` only then, but this does not seem to be reliable.)

For now, I have implemented the following solution:

```
//// html
<template name='notification'>
    <li class="list-group-item {{notificationClass}}">
        ...
    </li>
</template>

//// coffee
Template.notification.helpers
    notificationClass: ->
        if (this.read && UI._templateInstance().wasRead)
            undefined     # no highlight
        else 
            "list-group-item-info"     # highlight

Template.notification.rendered = ->
    this.wasRead = this.data.read
    this.data.markAsRead()    # ultimately updates the collection
```

that is, on `rendered` event I set the *template* property to remember whether this notification was read initially. This template property does not change as long as the template exists (and even if notification data changes, the template property is there). In template helper, instead of directly accessing the notification `read` property, I check template property.

This seems to work, but looks too complicated for me. So:

1. Are there any major disadvantages in this approach? For example, can template's `rendered` code be re-executed while a user stays on the page?
2. Is there some better approach for my problem?

Comment: Did you try setting `read` for all notifications in your template's `onDestroyed` callback? The only disadvantage I see with that approach is if the user closes the window before changing routes. Then again, how big of a deal is that?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I need to think on this, but overall it seems it would indeed be quite strange for the user if it is not marked when user closes the window.